# OnPostRender with Multiple camera's Unity3D

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine

Im trying to use GL & OnPostRender to render lines in Unity3D. It works fine if I just have one camera, however if I have multiple cameras (required for the oculus rift), the no matter what Ive tried, I cant get the lines to render in both camera viewports. Ive tried attaching the script to both cameras - setting the viewport etc and nothing works. If I attach the script to both cameras, then OnPostRender gets called once for each camera, but only the last one is drawn. IF I attach the script to only one camera and set the viewport to the second camera, I cant get the liones to draw in the second camera. Here is what I think should work:

```
Rect[] viewports;

            Camera[] cameras = null;
            if (Params.riftEnabled)
            {
                viewports = new Rect[2];
                viewports[0] = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width / 2, Screen.height);
                viewports[1] = viewports[0]; // new Rect(Screen.width / 2, 0, Screen.width / 2, Screen.height);
                GameObject ovrCameraController = (GameObject)GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ovrcamera");
                cameras = (Camera[])ovrCameraController.GetComponentsInChildren<Camera>();

            }
            else
            {
                viewports = new Rect[1];
                viewports[0] = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
                cameras = new Camera[1];
                cameras[0] = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < viewports.Length; i++)
            {
                SteeringManager.PrintVector("Cam " + i, cameras[i].transform.position);
                GL.PushMatrix();
                lineMaterial.SetPass(0);                                        
                GL.modelview = cameras[i].worldToCameraMatrix;
                GL.LoadProjectionMatrix(cameras[i].projectionMatrix);
                GL.Viewport(viewports[i]);
                lineMaterial.SetPass(0);
                GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
                foreach (Line line in lines)
                {
                     GL.Color(line.color);
                     GL.Vertex3(line.start.x, line.start.y, line.start.z);
                     GL.Vertex3(line.end.x, line.end.y, line.end.z);
                }
                GL.End();
                GL.PopMatrix();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add [yield WaitForEndOfFrame();] to your OnPostRender function.

```
function OnPostRenderer() {
    yield WaitForEndOfFrame();

    for (var i : int = 0; i < viewports.Length; i++)
    {
    GL.PushMatrix();
    lineMaterial.SetPass(0);                                    
    GL.modelview = cameras[i].worldToCameraMatrix;
    GL.LoadProjectionMatrix(cameras[i].projectionMatrix);
    GL.Viewport(viewports[i]);

    GL.Color(Color.white);
    GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
    for (var p : Vector3 in points) {
         GL.Vertex3(...);
         GL.Vertex3(...);
        }
    GL.End();
    GL.PopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Then attach this script to both cameras, it should work.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. It nearly works... Both cameras are displaying the lines now correctly, however in both viewports the lines are not being occluded correctly. It seems to be using the depth values from the main camera... For example, there are "holes" where the lines are being occluded by 3D objects from the main/full screen camera. Here is a screenshot: [image]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2400775/Untitled.png[image]. Those circular areas correspond to where the spheres are drawn on the main/fullscreen camera

Comment: Sorry.. that link to the image should be https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2400775/Untitled.png

Comment: hey @Verv Did you see my comments!

Comment: I have no idea, have you tried change clear flags? Or add one camera only draw the line?

Comment: I have being playing around with it more... Its one of the scripts attached to the rift cameras. If I remove the script, it works, (but obviously no VR). I'll investigate further